# calculating an angle of a pyramid

Tags: geometry, angle

For a practical problem I need to calculate the angle $c$ given the angles $a$ and $b$ in following drawing, but I have no idea how to do this or even where to begin.

[image]

Just for clarification:

$a$ is the Angle between $MA$ and $MB$

$b$ is the angle between $MA$ and $MD$

$c$ is the angle between $MD$ and $MC$

The angles with the $\bullet$ dot are $90^\circ$ angles.

Comment: Figure out the lengths of the lines and then calculate the angles with the law of cosines.

Comment: @DavidQuinn the OP specifically stated s/he had no idea where to begin so there doesn't seem to be any point in asking that.  S/he hasn't tried anything because she doesn't know what to try.

Comment: @fleablood Oh obviously, thank you, I already feared that I'd need some spherical trigonometry stuff, which I have no clue about=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=AD=BC$  and $y=AB=CD$. Note that angle $BAM = 90$ since $CD$ is perpendicular to plane $ADM$ and $CD$ is parallel to $AB$.

Then we have $$x=DM \tan b$$
$$y=DM \tan c\Rightarrow y=\frac {x}{\tan b}.\tan c$$

Also, $$y=AM\tan a$$ and $$AM=\frac {x}{\sin b}\Rightarrow y=\frac {x}{\sin b}.\tan a$$

Equating the expressions for $y$ gives $$\frac {x}{\tan b}.\tan c=\frac {x}{\sin b}.\tan a$$

Hence $$\tan c=\frac {\tan a}{\cos b}$$

Answer (score 0):

c = $\arcsin \frac {DC}{DM}$.

DC = AB; DM = $AM \cos b$.

$AB^2 = BM^2 + AM^2 - BM*AM*\cos a$

$BM = \sqrt{DC^2 + DM^2 + CB^2}$

CB = AD = $AM \sin b$

Put those altogether and something well fall out.